# Having trouble with deriving the state diagram for an exam problem

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, state-machines, sequential-logic

The Problem:
Derive the state diagram for a circuit that takes one input, A and gives out one output X, X is to be one, if and only if it detects a sequence "101" in A.

Understanding The problem:

if A=0001011011..

then X=00010010..

Now the first problem is how many states have I got?, for me its two, some of my colleagues argue that they are three.
the second question is how many bits do I need for each state, shouldn't they be three?
This isn't the whole problem, I should then use flip flops to implement it, but I'm stuck at the state diagram.

Comment: What will be the X if A = 1010101 ?

Comment: You need either three or four states, depending on whether or not overlapping patterns are allowed. In either case, it only requires 2 FFs to represent 3 or 4 states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1, A2 and A3 are shift register outputs (made of 3 D-flip flop) for simplicity.
A is your input sequence at IO1, X is your f(A)=seq.101=A1*!A2*A3.
table gives all states at every clock rise signal. Key D closed A=1; open A=0.
Clock key space close then open to get rise slope.
hope this is useful.

[image]

Comment: Even though I was more concerned with deriving the state diagram, I find this answer really helpful, thank you.